# Kendo grid datasource not getting updated when adding or editing records in child grids

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-datasource

If i try to add or update the grid records in the child grids, grid is updating but not the grid datasource.I tried to get the grid datasource from view which is also not having the updated data. can any one please tell me what's wrong with the following code

```
<div id="Grid"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
   var data = [{
  "BUCode": 6,
  "BUCodeName": "PrinterPix.com",
  "ClientCode": 1,
  "CreatedByCode": 1,
  "CreatedByName": "Bangalore Team",
  "DisplayCode": null,
  "IsActive": false,
  "ParentProductCode": 115,
  "ParentboProductCode": 115,
  "WorkCenterCode": 20,
  "WorkCenterName": "Print",
  "listRoutingPlanActivity": [{
    "ActivityCode": 12,
    "ActivityDisplayCode": null,
    "ActivityName": "Cut",
    "IsActive": false,
    "MachineHours": 0,
    "MachineSetupHours": 0,
    "StandardMinutes": 0,
    "WorkCenterCode": 20,
    "SequenceNumber": 1,
    "listActivityMaterial": [{
      "ActivityCode": 12,
      "Code": 0,
      "ActivityName": "Cut",
      "BUCode": 6,
      "BUCodeName": "PrinterPix.com",
      "ChildProductCode": 0,
      "ChildboProductCode": null,
      "ClientCode": 1,
      "CreatedByCode": 0,
      "IsActive": false,
      "ParentProductCode": 0,
      "ParentboProductCode": null,
      "ChildCategoryCode": 128,
      "ChildCategoryName": "_Raw Materials_",
      "ParentCategoryCode": 0,
      "ParentCategoryName": "",
      "Quantity": 0,
      "WorkCenterCode": 20
    }],
    "Code": 0,
    "OutputProductCode": 0,
    "OutPutBoProduct": ""
  }]
}, {
  "BUCode": 6,
  "BUCodeName": "PrinterPix.com",
  "ClientCode": 1,
  "CreatedByCode": 1,
  "CreatedByName": "Bangalore Team",
  "DisplayCode": null,
  "IsActive": false,
  "ParentProductCode": 115,
  "ParentboProductCode": 115,
  "WorkCenterCode": 23,
  "WorkCenterName": "Streatch",
  "listRoutingPlanActivity": [{
    "ActivityCode": 15,
    "ActivityDisplayCode": null,
    "ActivityName": "Stretched",
    "IsActive": false,
    "MachineHours": 0,
    "MachineSetupHours": 0,
    "StandardMinutes": 0,
    "WorkCenterCode": 23,
    "SequenceNumber": 2,
    "listActivityMaterial": [{
      "ActivityCode": 15,
      "Code": 0,
      "ActivityName": "Stretched",
      "BUCode": 6,
      "BUCodeName": "PrinterPix.com",
      "ChildProductCode": 0,
      "ChildboProductCode": null,
      "ClientCode": 1,
      "CreatedByCode": 0,
      "IsActive": false,
      "ParentProductCode": 0,
      "ParentboProductCode": null,
      "ChildCategoryCode": 128,
      "ChildCategoryName": "_Raw Materials_",
      "ParentCategoryCode": 0,
      "ParentCategoryName": "",
      "Quantity": 0,
      "WorkCenterCode": 23
    }],
    "Code": 0,
    "OutputProductCode": 0,
    "OutPutBoProduct": ""
  }]
}, {
  "BUCode": 6,
  "BUCodeName": "PrinterPix.com",
  "ClientCode": 1,
  "CreatedByCode": 1,
  "CreatedByName": "Bangalore Team",
  "DisplayCode": null,
  "IsActive": false,
  "ParentProductCode": 115,
  "ParentboProductCode": 115,
  "WorkCenterCode": 34,
  "WorkCenterName": "Sticking",
  "listRoutingPlanActivity": [{
    "ActivityCode": 66,
    "ActivityDisplayCode": null,
    "ActivityName": "Sticking",
    "IsActive": false,
    "MachineHours": 0,
    "MachineSetupHours": 0,
    "StandardMinutes": 0,
    "WorkCenterCode": 34,
    "SequenceNumber": 3,
    "listActivityMaterial": [{
      "ActivityCode": 66,
      "Code": 0,
      "ActivityName": "Sticking",
      "BUCode": 6,
      "BUCodeName": "PrinterPix.com",
      "ChildProductCode": 0,
      "ChildboProductCode": null,
      "ClientCode": 1,
      "CreatedByCode": 0,
      "IsActive": false,
      "ParentProductCode": 0,
      "ParentboProductCode": null,
      "ChildCategoryCode": 128,
      "ChildCategoryName": "_Raw Materials_",
      "ParentCategoryCode": 0,
      "ParentCategoryName": "",
      "Quantity": 0,
      "WorkCenterCode": 34
    }],
    "Code": 0,
    "OutputProductCode": 0,
    "OutPutBoProduct": ""
  }]
}];
var gridDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({

  transport: {
    read: function(options) {
      options.success(data);
    }
  },
  schema: {
    model: {
      id: "WorkCenterCode",
      fields: {
        WorkCenterCode: {
          editable: false
        },
        WorkCenterName: {
          editable: false,
        }
      }
    }
  },
});



$("#Grid").kendoGrid({
  autoBind:true,
dataSource: gridDataSource,
sortable: false,
pageable: false,
scrollable: true,
// detailInit: secondGridInit,                  
columns: [{
  field: "WorkCenterName",
  title: "Work Center Name"
}]
})

});


function secondGridInit(e) {

    console.log(JSON.stringify(e.data.listRoutingPlanActivity));
    var findByID = function(id) {
      return e.data.listRoutingPlanActivity.find(function(item) {
        return item.ActivityCode == id;
      });
    };
    $("<div id='activity' class='activity'/>").appendTo(e.detailCell).kendoGrid({
          dataSource: {
            transport: {
              read: function(options) {
                options.success(e.data.listRoutingPlanActivity.toJSON());
              },
              update: function(options) {
                e.data.dirty = true;
                options.success();
              },
            },
            schema: {
              model: {
                id: "ActivityCode",
                fields: {
                  WorkCenterCode: {
                    editable: false
                  },
                  ActivityCode: {
                    editable: false
                  },
                  ActivityName: {
                    editable: false
                  },
                  IsActive: {
                    editable: false,
                    defaultValue: true
                  },
                  StandardMinutes: {
                    type: "number"
                  },
                  MachineSetupHours: {
                    type: "number"
                  },
                  MachineHours: {
                    type: "number"
                  },
                }
              }
            }
          },
          scrollable: true,
          editable: "popup",
          columns: [{
              field: "ActivityName",
              title: "Activity"
            }, {
              field: "StandardMinutes",
              title: "Standard Time"
            }, {
              field: "MachineSetupHours",
              title: "Machine Setup Time"
            }, {
              field: "MachineHours",
              title: "Machine Hours"
            }, {
              command: "edit"
            },

          ]
        }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you initialize child grid it has own datasource formed from parent one and its a different object without refence to parent datasource.

So if you need updated data just retrive child grid datasouce for parent row and search in it.

Answer (score 0):

I too had this problem. When we change some data in kendo grid to show on UI only html changes not the dataSource.
So, the changes we are making in grid html are also have to be made in dataSource equally. 
Like this one

```
$("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.data()[i - 1].fclty_cd = faculty; // dataSource changes
$($($('#grid table tr[role=row]')[i]).find("td")[11]).text(faculty); // html changes
```

Comment: Could you tell me which event is best to handle this code?

Comment: I was doing it on an outside faculty dropdown change, you can do as per requirement or on dataBound event, like    dataBound: setTimeout(configureGridProperties, or
  dataBound: function () { setTimeout(configureGridProperties, 1); },